# How to write a function with generics?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to write a generic function as follows:

```
func convertItems<T>(#itemType: ItemType, rawItems: [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>]) -> [T] {

    var items = [MyModel]()
    // conversion code
    return items
}
```

Why does the compiler complain about 'MyModel not [being] identical to T'

Answer (score 0):

The return type is determined by the caller of `convertItems`, so you cannot force it to be `[MyModel]` from within the body of the function. Imagine someone called it with `T` being `SomeOtherModel`; you couldn't return `[MyModel]` then.

You either want this:

```
func convertItems<T>(#itemType: ItemType, rawItems: [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>]) -> [T] {
    var items = [T]()
    // conversion code
    return items
}
```

or this:

```
func convertItems(#itemType: ItemType, rawItems: [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>]) -> [MyModel] {
    var items = [MyModel]()
    // conversion code
    return items
}
```

instead.